# Python 3 img2pdf wrong order of images in pdf

Tags: python-3.x

I am working on a small program that takes images from a website and puts them into a pdf for easy access and simpler viewing.
I have a small problem as the img2pdf module seems to put the images into the pdf in the wrong order and I don't really get why.

It seems to put the files in order of 1,10,11.

```
import urllib.request
import os
import img2pdf


n = 50
all = 0
for counter in range(1,n+1):
      all = all + 1
      urllib.request.urlretrieve("https://website/images/"+str(all)+".jpg", "img"+str(all)+".jpg")


cwd = os.getcwd()
if all == 50:
      with open("output2.pdf", "wb") as f:
            f.write(img2pdf.convert([i for i in os.listdir(cwd) if i.endswith(".jpg")]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the filenames you're trying to read in, a guess is that your filenames include numbers that are not zero-padded. Lexicographic ordering (sorting in alphabetical order) of a sequence of files called *0.jpg*, *1.jpg*, ... *11.jpg* will lead to this ordering: *0.jpg*, *1.jpg*, *10.jpg*, *11.jpg*, *2.jpg*, *3.jpg*, *4.jpg*, *5.jpg*, *6.jpg*, *7.jpg*, *8.jpg*, *9.jpg*, because "1" < "2".

To combine your files such that 2 comes before 10, you can zero-pad the filenames (but also beware that some software will interpret leading zeros as indicators of an octal representation of a number, as opposed to just a leading zero.)

If you can't manipulate the filenames, then you could change your file-getting  code as follows: use a regular expression to extract the numbers, as `int` type, from the filenames of your entire list of files, then sort the list of filenames by those extracted numbers (which will be sorted as `int`, for which 2 < 10).